# How to get Approval submitted Date and Time for the existing data

Tags: apex, class, approval-process, update

Have written this code for to get Approval submitted Date but getting an error Incompatible value type Datetime for `Map<Id,Date>`

Please help me anyone here.

```
Map<id,Opportunity> accounts = new Map<ID,opportunity>([Select id, Submit_for_Booking__c From Opportunity where recordtypeid = '012600000009eKa']);
Map<ID,Date> approvalTimeStampMap = new Map<ID,Date>();

for(ProcessInstance approval : [Select createdDate,TargetObjectId From ProcessInstance Where TargetObjectId IN:accounts.keySet()]){
    approvalTimeStampMap.put(approval.TargetObjectId, approval.createdDate);
}

List<Opportunity> accountsSubmittedForApproval = new List<Opportunity>();

for(Opportunity acc : accounts.values()){
    acc.Submit_for_Booking__c = approvalTimeStampMap.get(acc.id); 
    accountsSubmittedForApproval.add(acc);
}

update accountsSubmittedForApproval;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
Map<ID,Date> approvalTimeStampMap = new Map<ID,Date>();
```

to

```
Map<ID,DateTime> approvalTimeStampMap = new Map<ID,DateTime>();
```

**CreatedDate** is a Date-Time field. Make sure that `Submit_for_Booking__c` is a Date-Time field.

Update:

> Illegal ''assignment from Datetime to Boolean' means you are assigning
>   a date time value in boolean type. Here Date time is only
>   approvalTimeStampMap. So, verfiy that Submit_for_Booking__c is a Date
>   Time field.

Comment: Thank you for quick respond and I tried that also. It's giving an error is Illegal ''assignment from Datetime to Boolean''.

Comment: @VivekanandaReddy for which line? Is Submit_for_Booking__c is a checkbox?

Comment: It's not showing any line here and updating the code from developer console. I think it's weird error.

Comment: `Illegal ''assignment from Datetime to Boolean'` means you are assigning a date time value in boolean type. Here Date time is only `approvalTimeStampMap`. So, verfiy that Submit_for_Booking__c is a Date Time field. @VivekanandaReddy

Comment: Yes, you are right. I took wrong filed. Thank you so much Ashwani :)